# Storing $K$ numbers with ordering

Tags: data-structures

Let $S$ be a sequence of $k$ many numbers. The position of the number in the $S$ matters. In the $S$ there are only $j$ many different numbers are there means $S$ contains many duplicates. Position is a query which needed to be answered, position(i) returns the element at position $i$ in $S$.

Trivial way to store them is using array which will takes $O(S)$ space and position can be solved in $O(1)$ time.

I am looking for a representation that takes $O(j)$ space (or somewhere near to it) and such that position can be solved in $O(1)$(even in more time is also ok)?

Please suggest some papers also.

Comment: I don't understand what you need completely but why would a hashset not satisfy your requirements? Btw the array as described by you only works if the numbers are (more or less) consecutive.

Comment: @ Daniel Numbers are different and they are $1,2,\ldots, j$. I am looking for deterministic data str.

Comment: What is the element in position $i$ of a set? Sets do not have order.

Comment: @orlp  You can see them as a some sequence.

Answer (score 1):

What you ask is impossible, assuming you don't really mean sets (as sets are orderless), but ordered tuples. Consider $j=2$, then you effectively have $k$-length binary strings. And those require $\Omega(k)$ storage.

Comment: Ok if space is say $\Omega(K)$ then what is position query time.